# How to implement drag'n'drop for nested lists in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating my sidebar component which is divided by sections. What I want to do, is to implement drag'n'drop functionality. But here is the problem, here is how those sections look like in code:

```js
const sidebarSections = [
  {
    name: 'General',
    routePrefix: '/general',
    elements: [
      {
        name: "Home",
        icon: <HomeIcon/>,
        href: "/home",
        show: true
      },
      {
        name: "Clients",
        icon: <SupervisedUserCircleIcon/>,
        href: "/clients",
        show: true
      },
      {
        name: "ACL",
        icon: <ManageAccountsIcon/>,
        href: "/acl",
        show: true
      },
      {
        name: "Modify roles",
        icon: <AddModeratorIcon/>,
        href: "/roles",
        show: true
      },
    ]
  },
...
```

Every section - in this case `General` - has its `elements`. As you probably guess, I want to implement drag'n'drop only for those elements and not for whole `sidebarSections`.

Here is how this sidebar list looks like in code:

```js
const [sidebar, setSidebar] = React.useState(sidebarSections)

const list = () => (
<Box
  sx={{
    width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250,
  }}
  role="presentation"
  onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
>
  <List>
    {sidebarSections.map((section, key) => (
      <Box
        key={key}
        sx={{
          marginTop: 2,
        }}
      >
        {section.name ? (
          <ListItemText
            sx={{
              px: 2,
              color: 'primary.light',
            }}
          >
            {section.name}
          </ListItemText>
        ) : null}
        <List>
          {section.elements.map((subsection) =>
            subsection.show || settings ? (
              <ListItem key={subsection.name}>
                {settings ? (
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={subsection.show}
                    onChange={() => {
                      subsection.show = !subsection.show;
                      setSidebar((prev) => [...prev]);
                    }}
                  />
                ) : null}
                <Link href={section.routePrefix + subsection.href} passHref>
                  <Button
                    sx={{
                      color: router.pathname.includes(
                        `${section.routePrefix + subsection.href}`
                      )
                        ? "secondary.main"
                        : "primary.main",
                      width: "100%",
                      justifyContent: "start"
                    }}
                    startIcon={subsection.icon}
                  >
                    {subsection.name}
                  </Button>
                </Link>
              </ListItem>
            ) : null
          )}
        </List>
        <Divider
          sx={{color: 'primary.light'}}
        />
      </Box>
    ))}
  </List>
</Box>
)
```

I was using [this](https://contactmentor.com/react-drag-drop-list/) guide while was trying to do this, but, because of nested list I wasn't able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem. Instead of `{subsection.name}` you can pass your component (`Button` in my case).

`DragDropContext` has to be only on list where you want have drag'n'drop enabled. Also I have changed `handleDrop` function to make it parse nested list and render it more time to show new order of elements.

```js
  const handleDrop = (droppedItem) => {
    if (!droppedItem.destination) return;
    const updatedSidebar = [...sidebar];

    updatedSidebar.forEach(section => {
      section.elements.forEach(subsection => {
        if (droppedItem.draggableId === subsection.name) {
          const [reorderedItem] = section.elements.splice(droppedItem.source.index, 1);
          section.elements.splice(droppedItem.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
        }
      })
    })

    setSidebar(updatedSidebar);
  };

  const list2 = () => (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250,
      }}
      role="presentation"
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      <List>
        {sidebarSections.map((section, key) => (
          <Box
            key={key}
            sx={{
              marginTop: 2,
            }}
          >
            {section.name ? (
              <ListItemText
                sx={{
                  px: 2,
                  color: 'primary.light',
                }}
              >
                {section.name}
              </ListItemText>
            ) : null}
            <List>
              <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDrop}>
                <Droppable droppableId="list-container">
                  {(provided) => (
                    <div
                      className="list-container"
                      {...provided.droppableProps}
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                    >

                      {section.elements.map((subsection, index) =>
                        subsection.show || settings ? (
                          <ListItem key={subsection.name}>
                            {settings ? (
                              <Box>
                                <Draggable key={subsection.name} draggableId={subsection.name} index={index}>
                                  {(provided) => (
                                    <div
                                      className="item-container"
                                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                                    >
                                      {subsection.name}
                                    </div>
                                  )}
                                </Draggable>
                                {provided.placeholder}
                              </Box>
                            ) : null}
                            {!settings ? (
                              <Link href={section.routePrefix + subsection.href} passHref>
                                <Button
                                  sx={{
                                    color: router.pathname.includes(
                                      `${section.routePrefix + subsection.href}`
                                    )
                                      ? "secondary.main"
                                      : "primary.main",
                                    width: "100%",
                                    justifyContent: "start"
                                  }}
                                  startIcon={subsection.icon}
                                >
                                  {subsection.name}
                                </Button>
                              </Link>
                            ) : null}
                          </ListItem>
                        ) : null
                      )}

                    </div>
                  )}
                </Droppable>
              </DragDropContext>
            </List>
            <Divider
              sx={{color: 'primary.light'}}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
```